# fread gives empty results and glibc detected

Tags: c

I want to read a txt/dat file and I am using the following code but it doesn't load the file because it prints zero values for every pointer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

int main( int argc, const char* argv[] ){

    const int N = 10;
    double *t = (double*) malloc ( N * sizeof(double) ); 
    double *x = (double*) malloc ( N * sizeof(double) );
    double *v = (double*) malloc ( N * sizeof(double) );

    FILE * theFile;
    theFile = fopen( "testFile.dat", "w" );
    assert( NULL != theFile );

    printf("\n BEFORE \n");
    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ ) 
    {   

        t[ i ] = i;
        x[ i ] = i + 1;
        v[ i ] = i * 2;

        // write result to file
        fprintf ( theFile, "%5.5f \t %5.5f \t %5.5f \n", t[ i ], x[ i ], v[ i ] );        

        printf( "%5.5f \t %5.5f \t %5.5f \n", t[ i ], x[ i ], v[ i ] );

    }

    fclose( theFile );

    // open file for reading
    theFile = fopen( "testFile.dat", "r" );
    assert( NULL != theFile );

    const int buffSize = 3;
    double buffer[ buffSize ];

    fread( buffer, buffSize , N , theFile );

    t = &buffer[ 0 ];
    x = &buffer[ 1 ];
    v = &buffer[ 2 ];

    printf("\n AFTER \n");
    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
        printf( "%5.5f \t %5.5f \t %5.5f \n", t[ i ],x[ i ],v[ i ] );

    fclose( theFile );

    free ( t );
    free ( x );
    free ( v );


return 0;

}
```

Also , in the case we had different datatypes ,for example 2 doubles and 1 integer , I would use 2 different buffers and call the fread 2 times?

Comment: What are you trying to do here `t = &buffer[ 0 ];`? what do you think it does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read back the values you should read each line as a string and parse it to extract the float values this is your code, fixed to do that

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

int main( int argc, const char* argv[] ){

    const int N = 10;
    double *t = malloc ( N * sizeof(double) );
    double *x = malloc ( N * sizeof(double) );
    double *v = malloc ( N * sizeof(double) );

    FILE * theFile;

    theFile = fopen( "testFile.dat", "w" );
    assert( NULL != theFile );

    printf("\n BEFORE \n");
    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {

        t[ i ] = i;
        x[ i ] = i + 1;
        v[ i ] = i * 2;

        // write result to file
        fprintf ( theFile, "%5.5f \t %5.5f \t %5.5f \n", t[ i ], x[ i ], v[ i ] );

        printf( "%5.5f \t %5.5f \t %5.5f \n", t[ i ], x[ i ], v[ i ] );

    }

    fclose( theFile );

    // open file for reading
    theFile = fopen( "testFile.dat", "r" );
    assert( NULL != theFile );

    int i = 0;
    while (fscanf(theFile, "%f%f%f", &(t[i]), &(x[i]), &(v[i])) == 3) i++;

    printf("\n AFTER \n");
    for ( int i = 0; i < N ; i++ )
        printf( "%5.5f \t %5.5f \t %5.5f \n", t[ i ],x[ i ],v[ i ] );

    fclose( theFile );

    free ( t );
    free ( x );
    free ( v );


    return 0;
}
```

Your original code, declares an array of size `3` and reassings the pointers `t` `x` and `v` to point to the array, there are problems in the following `for` and the calls to `free` will try to `free` the array instead of the original `malloc`ed pointers.

If you don't need the data to be stored in human readable format, then you can use this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

int main( int argc, const char* argv[] ){

    const int N = 10;
    double *t = malloc ( N * sizeof(double) );
    double *x = malloc ( N * sizeof(double) );
    double *v = malloc ( N * sizeof(double) );

    FILE * theFile;

    theFile = fopen( "testFile.dat", "w" );
    assert( NULL != theFile );

    printf("\n BEFORE \n");
    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {

        t[ i ] = i;
        x[ i ] = i + 1;
        v[ i ] = i * 2;

        // write result to file
        //fprintf ( theFile, "%5.5f \t %5.5f \t %5.5f \n", t[ i ], x[ i ], v[ i ] );

        printf( "%5.5f \t %5.5f \t %5.5f \n", t[ i ], x[ i ], v[ i ] );

    }
    fwrite(t, sizeof(double), N, theFile);
    fwrite(x, sizeof(double), N, theFile);
    fwrite(v, sizeof(double), N, theFile);

    fclose( theFile );

    // open file for reading
    theFile = fopen( "testFile.dat", "r" );
    assert( NULL != theFile );

    fread(t, sizeof(double), N, theFile);
    fread(x, sizeof(double), N, theFile);
    fread(v, sizeof(double), N, theFile);

    printf("\n AFTER \n");
    for ( int i = 0; i < N ; i++ )
        printf( "%5.5f \t %5.5f \t %5.5f \n", t[ i ],x[ i ],v[ i ] );

    fclose( theFile );

    free ( t );
    free ( x );
    free ( v );


    return 0;
}
```

And as a final note, always check the return value of `malloc`, it will return `NULL` on failure, indicating the there is not enough memory in your system, if you don't check it, and it returned `NULL`, you will have a segmentation fault in your first attempt to access it.

Even if this code works, it has serious bad practice issues i fixed the code to make it more robust

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

int main( int argc, const char* argv[] ){

    const int N = 10;
    FILE *theFile = NULL;
    double *t = NULL;
    double *x = NULL;
    double *v = NULL;
    int errorCode = 0;

    t = malloc ( N * sizeof(double) );
    if (t == NULL)
        goto abort;
    x = malloc ( N * sizeof(double) );
    if (x == NULL)
        goto abort;
    v = malloc ( N * sizeof(double) );
    if (v == NULL)
        goto abort;

    theFile = fopen( "testFile.dat", "w" );
    if (theFile == NULL)
        goto abort;
    printf("\n BEFORE \n");
    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {

        t[ i ] = i;
        x[ i ] = i + 1;
        v[ i ] = i * 2;

        // write result to file
        fprintf ( theFile, "%5.5f \t %5.5f \t %5.5f \n", t[ i ], x[ i ], v[ i ] );

        printf( "%5.5f \t %5.5f \t %5.5f \n", t[ i ], x[ i ], v[ i ] );

    }
    fclose( theFile );

    // open file for reading
    theFile = fopen( "testFile.dat", "r" );
    if (theFile == NULL)
        goto abort;

    int i = 0;
    while (i < N) /* stop when you have read enough lines to fit t, x and v */
    {
        if (fscanf(theFile, "%f%f%f", &(t[i]), &(x[i]), &(v[i])) == 3)
        {
            /* This will not happen since you just created the file with the appropriate content
                * but the good practice here is to check for any problem during the read
                */
            errorCode = -1;

            printf("malformed line found in file.\n");
            goto abort;
        }
        i++;
    }

    printf("\n AFTER \n");
    for ( int i = 0; i < N ; i++ )
        printf( "%5.5f \t %5.5f \t %5.5f \n", t[ i ],x[ i ],v[ i ] );

abort: /* note: This prevents repeating the cleanup code */
    if (theFile != NULL)
        fclose( theFile );
    if (t != NULL)
        free ( t );
    if (x != NULL)
        free ( x );
    if (v != NULL)
        free ( v );

    return errorCode;
}
```

Comment: @George It's not, it's just that you where storing text in the file and then trying to read it as binary data, somewhat, because your `fread` call `fread(buffer, buffSize, N, theFile)` means, read `N` elements, each of size `buffSize` from `theFile` into the buffer. And `buffer` will only hold `3` `double` values not `3N`, so you where actually overflowing `buffer` and reading text into it.

Comment: I don't care about `-2` reputation, but downvote without leaving a comment is not very constructive, it's stupid unless it is very clear why the downvote.

Answer (score 1):

Your `fread` call writes past the end of `buffer`:

```
fread( buffer, buffSize , N , theFile );
```

How best to fix this depends on what exactly you're trying to do. For example, to read three doubles into `buffer`, this should read:

```
fread( buffer, sizeof(double), buffSize , theFile );
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use fprintf to write to the file then you should use fscanf, with the same format argument, to read it back. Also, you messed up buffering in the reading part. I guess your code for reading should look like the following (with only the most essential modifications):

```
// open file for reading
    theFile = fopen( "testFile.dat", "r" );
    assert( NULL != theFile );

    const int buffSize = 3;
    double buffer[ buffSize ];
    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        fscanf(theFile, "%f \t %f \t %f \n", &buffer[0], &buffer[1], &buffer[2]);
        t[i] = buffer[ 0 ];
        x[i] = &buffer[ 1 ];
        v[i] = &buffer[ 2 ];
    }


    printf("\n AFTER \n");
    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%5.5f \t %5.5f \t %5.5f \n", t[ i ],x[ i ],v[ i ] );
    }

    fclose( theFile );
```

Comment: :The results I am taking are still zero with this code

Comment: You dont check if `fscanf` did read the three arguments, and hence you are potentially accessing uninitialized valules.

Answer (score 1):

Your `fprintf()` is writing the doubles to the file as strings (delimited by tabs) - that's what the conversion specifier `%5.5f` does - it converts the doubles to a string representation. An example is the first line of testFile.dat:

```
0.00000          1.00000         0.00000
```

Later you are trying to read the doubles back in, but you are trying to read them as though they are raw doubles, not as strings. You should be able to use `fscanf()` to read the doubles back in.

Answer (score 1):

```
the following code:
1) compiles with no warnings 
2) contains commentary about each step 
   and what is wrong with the code

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h> // <-- using assert is not suitable for production code

int main() // <-- if not accessing argc and argv, do not included them
{
    // note, I do not have the C99 version of the compiler, 
    //       so moved the definition of 'i'
    int i; // loop counter

    const int N = 10;
    // <-- need to check for successful operation of each following call to malloc())
    double *t = (double*) malloc ( N * sizeof(double) );
    double *x = (double*) malloc ( N * sizeof(double) );
    double *v = (double*) malloc ( N * sizeof(double) );

    FILE * theFile;
    theFile = fopen( "testFile.dat", "w" );
    assert( NULL != theFile ); // <-- better to use perror and exit
                               //     so reason for fopen failure is broadcast

    printf("\n BEFORE \n");
    for ( i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {

        t[ i ] = i;
        x[ i ] = i + 1;
        v[ i ] = i * 2;

        // write result to file
        fprintf ( theFile, "%5.5f \t %5.5f \t %5.5f \n", t[ i ], x[ i ], v[ i ] );

        printf( "%5.5f \t %5.5f \t %5.5f \n", t[ i ], x[ i ], v[ i ] );

    }

    fclose( theFile );

    // open file for reading
    theFile = fopen( "testFile.dat", "r" );
    assert( NULL != theFile ); // <-- better to use perror and exit
                               //     so reason for fopen failure is broadcast

    const int buffSize = 3;
    double buffer[ buffSize ];

    // note: the file was written with three doubles, separated by ' \t '
    //       it needs to be read the same way
    //       suggest using fgets() to control a loop, 
    //       along with the strtok() and strtod() library functions
    //       to extract values from each line of the file
    fread( buffer, buffSize , N , theFile ); // <-- this will overflow buffer,
                                             //     resulting in undefined behaviour
                                             //     leading to a seg fault event

    t = &buffer[ 0 ];
    x = &buffer[ 1 ];
    v = &buffer[ 2 ];

    printf("\n AFTER \n");
    for ( i = 0; i < N; i++ )
        printf( "%5.5f \t %5.5f \t %5.5f \n", t[ i ],x[ i ],v[ i ] );

    fclose( theFile );

    free ( t );
    free ( x );
    free ( v );


return 0;

} // end function: main
```